# How do I split a string given an array of split positions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, split

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and Rails 5.  I have an array of indexes within a line

[5, 8, 10]

How do I take the above array, and a string, and form anotehr array of strings that are split by the above indexes?  FOr instance, if the string is

```
abcdefghijklmn
```

and split it based ont eh above indexes, I would have an array with the following strings

```
abcde
fgh
ij
klmn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
str = "abcdefghijklmn"
positions = [5, 8, 10]

parts = [0, *positions, str.size].each_cons(2).map { |a, b| str[a...b] }
# => ["abcde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn"]
```

Or,

If the positions are constant and known ahead of runtime (for example if they were the format for a phone number or credit card) just use a regexp

```
str.match(/(.....)(...)(..)(.*)/).captures
# => ["abcde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the Job done

```
str = "abcdefghijklmn"
arr_1 = [5, 8, 10]
arr_2, prev = [], 0

(arr_1.length + 1).times do |x|
  if arr_1[x] == nil then arr_1[x] = str.size end
  arr_2 << str[prev..arr_1[x] -1]
  prev = arr_1[x] 
end

p arr_2

---------------------------------------
     Program Run Output

["abcde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn"]
---------------------------------------
```

I hope this Helps